# How to access an Image Dom Element with Vaadin/GWT?

Tags: gwt, dom, vaadin

I have an HTML Dom looking like this:

```
<div class="mydiv" id="mydivId">
  <img src="../xyz.png" class="gwt-Image imgWrapper" draggable="false">
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the img Source, so i made the following to access the image without success:

```
Image imageElement = (Image) Document.get()
                    .getElementById("mydivId")
                    .getElementsByTagName("img").getItem(0);
```

How can i get the `<img>` dom element as Image then change its Source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `ImageElement` with

```
ImageElement image = (ImageElement) DOM.getElementById("mydivId").getFirstChildElement();
```

or create an `Image` widget by wrapping the existing img element like in

```
Image img = Image.wrap(DOM.getElementById("mydivId").getFirstChildElement());
```

As mentioned by Saeed Zarinfam it gets easier if you assign an unique id to the image itself.

Comment: your method is more the way i want!! it is possible then to change the img src??

Comment: Of course. Just call `img.setUrl(newUrl)` or `image.setSrc(newUrl)` depending on what solution you chose.

Comment: Give the code example that doesn't work please. It's kinda hard to guess what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign an id to your image tag:

```
<div class="mydiv" id="mydivId">
  <img src="../xyz.png" class="gwt-Image imgWrapper" draggable="false" id="myImgId">
</div>
```

Then you can access to it using following code:

```
Element elem = DOM.getElementById("myImgId");
Window.alert(elem.getAttribute("src"));
```

Or if you do not want to assign an id to your image tag, you can use following code:

```
Element elem = DOM.getElementById("mydivId");
Window.alert(elem.getFirstChildElement().getAttribute("src"));
```

Comment: Thanks Saeed!! but i can assign an Id because `image.addStyleName(styleName);` addStyleName dont set Id for an Image object.

Comment: Your welcome, I did not say you can not i said "you do not want". If my answer was good for you please accept it.

Comment: sorry.... i cant assign :) ... do you have a method to assign id to Image Object? i cant find any!!

Comment: DOM.getElementById("mydivId").getFirstChildElement().setId("someId");

Comment: Thank you! is there a function similar to addStyleName to set ID??

Comment: DOM.getElementById("mydivId").getFirstChildElement().setClassName("cssClass");

Comment: Thanks Saeed!! i check this now if its work for me and i will vote! :)