# Vaadin : How to get Element by ID?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

How to get HTML Elmement (or DOM) in Vaadin ?
In GWT I can use as `DOM.getElementById("myId");`
I can set **id** attribute on my Vaadin components by `setId()` method. For example:

```
    Button button = new Button("Say Hello");
    button.setId("myButton");
```

So, how can I retrieve this DOM Element in Vaadin ?

Comment: I am sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948089/how-to-access-an-image-dom-element-with-vaadin-gwt) question and answers are not solution for me because these are for GWT not for vaadin.

Comment: Vaadin is a server-side framework so you cannot access a HTML element on the server-side code.

Comment: @HenriKerola True in Vaadin 6-7-8, but not in 10 and later, known as [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow). The new *Flow* generation replaces [*GWT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) for [*Web Components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components). Now we do have direct access to the DOM from the Java-based server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Vaadin 10 (*Vaadin Flow*)

The new [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow) generation replaces the internal use of [*GWT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) for [*Web Components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components).

This new architecture provides us with easy direct access to the DOM from the Java-based server-side, if you so desire. You can read the DOM, and you can manipulate elements in the DOM. Read about the new Element API [in the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/element-api/tutorial-properties-attributes.html).

## Vaadin 6, 7, & 8 ([*Vaadin Framework*](https://vaadin.com/framework/))

This Answer expands on the comment by [Vaadin expert](https://vaadin.com/company), [Henri Kerola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270910/henri-kerola).

[Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) is a server-side app framework. It's purpose is to shield the app developer from the details of [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), [GWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit), [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), and such web technologies. The app developer writes in pure [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) (and maybe a tiny touch of CSS for tweaking). Vaadin transparently and auto-magically generates the HTML-CSS-JavaScript-GWT-DOM necessary to render a representation of the app’s user-interface within a web browser.

So there is no way to access the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) from that Java server-side, nor any need to do so generally.

If you want to take control of the web technologies then [Vaadin](https://www.Vaadin.com/) is probably not the best framework for you.

Comment: And you you couldn't get element by id in Vaadin? See these links: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948089/how-to-access-an-image-dom-element-with-vaadin-gwt , 

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dom , 

https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.8/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html

Comment: You can create add-on.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
public static Component findComponentById(HasComponents root, String id) {
    for (Component child : root) {
        if (id.equals(child.getId())) {
            return child; // found it!
        } else if (child instanceof HasComponents) { // recursively go through all children that themselves have children
            Component result = findComponentById((HasComponents) child, id);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // none was found
}
```

Source: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/3199995/3199994

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin8 you may try this:

JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("document.getElementById('refreshButton').click()");